# ng-tables using custom names for my filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to use ng-table filters with a search backend called ransack (under Ruby on Rails) is there a way to use custom filter names?

eg:

```
description_cont
```

When used with ransack this will look for any text within description.

Comment: Can you provide some code example? I don't really get the meaning of the question.

Comment: Hmm, I think this has more to do with the backend now that I've spent a lot more time with it.

Comment: Did you take a look at examples in the ng-tables site? http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/11

Comment: Yeah I've fixed this but cannot close or delete it as it's got a bounty on it.